# PlayN: clear part of an Image

Tags: image, playn

I would like to overwrite/clear part of an image, using transparent colour in PlayN. Is this possible somehow? (PlayN 1.3.1)

Here is a sample code I did:

```
  @Override
  public void init() {
    // create and add background image layer
    Image bgImage = assetManager().getImage("images/bg.png");
    ImageLayer bgLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage);
    graphics().rootLayer().add(bgLayer);
    SurfaceLayer surfaceLayer = graphics().createSurfaceLayer(640, 480);
    CanvasImage image = graphics().createImage(640, 480);
    surfaceLayer.surface().setFillColor(0xff000000);
    surfaceLayer.surface().fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    surfaceLayer.surface().setFillColor(0x00000000);
    surfaceLayer.surface().fillRect(150, 150, 50, 50);
    graphics().rootLayer().add(surfaceLayer);
    image.canvas().setFillColor(0xff000000);
    image.canvas().fillCircle(300, 300, 100);
    image.canvas().setFillColor(0x00000000);
    image.canvas().fillCircle(300, 300, 50);
    graphics().rootLayer().add(graphics().createImageLayer(image));
  }
```

So I have tried with `SurfaceLayer`, and also with `ImageLayer` none of them were helping (I guess this way it is not possible to overwrite parts). I wanted to have two intersecting rectangles, and circles, but I only see one of each.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing or filling with a transparent color just results in nothing being drawn. The only operation you have in PlayN to clear pixel data is Canvas.clear(), which clears the entire image. You *could* also make use of GWT's access to canvas pixel operations and set those pixels manually >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492578/1117740

For an easy solution ...

... to clear a rectangle you could just make a copy of your image, then clear you image and draw back the sections you wish to retain.

Obviously you couldn't do that with a circle so easily, though you *could* use Bresenham's circle drawing algorithm and copy back the segments of each scan line you wish to retain.

Comment: Thanks, this is a way to go, but I'm afraid it will not help with the GC issues on Android. (Making things transparent again would not require to recreate the whole layer/image and dispose them.)